# Type R$attr is defined multiple times:

Tags: android, apk

Type com.MyuserName.Myapp.R$attr is defined multiple times: C:\Users\MyuserName\AndroidStudioProjects\Myapp\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\com\MyNameorCo\Myapp\R$attr.dex, C:\Users\MyuserName\AndroidStudioProjects\Myapp\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\af7c35b34077cbe8ea4d932fb0ad55adaf240356751534f7df24b806e03d9f7e_3.jar:classes.dex.
I deleted af7c35b34077cbe8ea4d932fb0ad55adaf240356751534f7df24b806e03d9f7e_3.jar:classes.dex and it was recreated again by the compiler. I retried with R$attr.dex and the same error.
So it isn't an internal Android error? because nothing to do with this when building an APK as written code from our side or settings

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just to delete the R.java if you have (usually from Eclipse export-import). Android studio will generate its own R.jar and can be used as R.referenceVar
This solves any defined multiple times in form ...$[attribute]